# A Word/Phrase Meaning Something Complex and almost Un-Understandable

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a world/phrase that describes something that is really complex, and is complex to the point where it could be un-understandable.

Comment: We don't usually work on such ventures because they do not serve our purposes of matching one question with one solid answer that serves for a long time. Such ventures are strictly opinion-based rather than having 'answers,' and we could supply many answers that get rejected -- less fruitful for us than it sounds..

Comment: Conundrum, an intricate and difficult problem (MW).  But this has another connotation as a riddle.

Comment: there is the term Byzantine ~(of a system or situation) excessively complicated, typically involving a great deal of administrative detail.~ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/byzantine but its connotation is sort of 'unnecessarily complex' rather than extremely complex... plus I'm not fond of elevated words... I'd prefer something general a freshman in high school was familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for labyrinthine

Labyrinthine

> (of a system) intricate and confusing

e.g. Labyrinthine concepts scare me

Comment: Thanks, might actually use it, looks like a pretty neat world, thanks once again :)

Comment: I'm glad the answer has been helpful...

Comment: @TheRedstoner17 Please accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: @HimabunduBoddupalli there probably won't be only one definitive answer to this - see Yosef Baskin's comment above.  You could ask for an upvote though! (When they have enough reputation)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the word "incomprehensible".

According to Merriam Webster it means exactly what it sounds like: "impossible to comprehend".

Answer (score 0):

Arcane is a word I would use in this situation.

[Definition of arcane](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arcane)

> First Known Use: 1547
>
> 1. known or knowable only to a few people
>
> e.g. *arcane* rites; an *arcane* ritual; ***arcane* explanations**; ***arcane* technical details**
>
> - Reading medical journals can be a real headache. Sure, the topics are important, but the demands of scientific accuracy make for dense, technical prose. The language is almost always an agony of ***arcane*** jargon and clunky grammar.

Comment: Of course! You could add a definition from a reputable dictionary too, to prove you've got the right word :)

Answer (score 0):

Baroque:

> characterized by grotesqueness, extravagance, complexity, or flamboyance

Answer (score 0):

> **opaque**
>
> adjective
>
> 4. hard to understand; not clear or lucid; obscure:
>
> *The problem remains opaque despite explanations.*
>
> [[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/opaque)]